# Safari/Firefox not calculating correctly jQuery .height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, height

On initial page load, I need the `header` image height to be calculated, and then push the `main` section below it. (The `header` is fixed and without this, `main` would display at the top of the page). In Chrome, there's no issue, everything works fine. In Safari and Firefox, `main` displays 20px from the top of the browser, which is the margin of `main`.

JS:

```
var headerHeight = $('#head-image').height();

function pageSetup(elementHeight) {
    var main = $('main');
    var headerHeightPx = elementHeight +'px';
    main.css({'paddingTop': headerHeightPx});
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    pageSetup(headerHeight);
});
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    ...
    <div class='foo'>
        <img src='image.jpg' id='head-image'>
    </div>
<header>
<main>
    ...
</main>
```

CSS:

```
#head-image {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

main {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: You should set `var headerHeight = $('#head-image').height();` inside window load handler, to wait image to be fully rendered. Chrome must be using the cached version

Comment: @A.Wolff Dumber than dumb. Cheers!